# NSDecimalNumberPlaceHolder Leak

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-leaks, instruments, nsdecimalnumber

I have an iPad app that I am testing in Instruments before beta testing. I have gotten rid of all memory leaks except one, and I can't find any information on it. I am baffled as to what to do, since my code never mentions the leaking object which is an instance of NSDecimalNumberPlaceHolder.

For sure I am using NSDecimalNumber. I create 2 decimals per user operation and each I time I run a cycle of the app (which performs some math operation on the two NSDecimalNumbers) I generate four instances of this NSDecimalPlaceHolder thing. Since I do not know how it gets created, I do not know how to release or dealloc it so as to not generate these 16 btye leaks over and over again.

Is it possible that these are not really leaks?

I have run the XCode Analyzer and it reports no issues.

What I'm doing is this:

I send a decimal number from my controller over to my model (analyzer_) which performs the operations and sends back the result.

```
[[self analyzer_] setOperand:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:anotherStringValue]];
```

The setOperand method looks like this:

```
-(void)setOperand:(NSDecimalNumber*)theOperand
{
NSLog(@"setOperand called");
operand_ = theOperand;
//[operand_ retain];
```

}

Note that if I don't retain operand_ "somewhere" I get a BAD_ACCESS crash. I currently retain and release it later where the operand and the previously provided operand (queuedOperand_) are operated upon. For example:

```
{
[self performQueuedOperation];
queuedOperation_ = operation;
queuedOperand_ = operand_;
}   

return operand_;
[operand_ release];
```

where performQueuedOperation is:

```
-(void)performQueuedOperation
{
   [operand_ retain];
   if ([@"+" isEqualToString:queuedOperation_]) 
   {
    @try
    {
    operand_ = [queuedOperand_ decimalNumberByAdding:operand_];
    }
    @catch (NSException *NSDecimalNumberOverFlowException)
    {
    //viewController will send decimal point error message
    }
   <etc for the other operations>
}
```

Let me know if this is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: NSDecimalNumberPlaceHolder is probably the concrete class that is being allocated when you're using NSDecimalNumber. Try posting some code to look at. Also, what happens when you run the analyzer on your code?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @ThomasW. I edited the question to provide the requested information.

Comment: I think you'll have to clean up you code with a good understanding of how retain/release should work. The setOperand: method should probably be retaining the new value of operand_ and releasing the old value. If you don't need to do anything special in the setter, you should consider changing operand_ to a @property with retain. Other uses of retain and release should be cleaned up. The 'return operand_; [operand_ release];' code will not release operand_, because the return will exit the method. (The compiler should be issuing a warning for that.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. No warnings. I've tried it both ways (with and without @property and with and without both a retain and release in the setter). I will clean up those ones after the return. Trying to release and retain it in the setOperand method ends up giving me 2 unreleased instances of NSDecimalNumber from my app (I do not know why). The placeholders are generated by Foundation. I have a few ideas though. I'll report back when I have tried them.

Comment: Be sure to release operand_ in your dealloc method.

Comment: Also be sure to remove the unnecessary retains like the one in performQueuedOperation.

Comment: I do release it in dealloc and I got rid of the retain in queuedOperation. However I have one more retain in the method that calls performQueuedOperation (performOperation) and I can't get rid of it or else I quickly crash by attempting to send a message to queuedOperand_ which has been deallocated. It turns out that NSDecimalPlaceHolder is not the problem. It is my NSDecimalNumbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try Heapshot in Instruments, see: [When is a Leak not a Leak?](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/)

If there is still a pointer to the memory that is no longer used it is not a leak but it is lost memory.  I use Heapshot often, it really works great.  Also turn on recording reference counting in the Allocations tool and drill down.  Here is a screenshot: [image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not an expert on Instruments but I don't see how Heapshot helps isolate the problem. I do see by reference counting though that I am always abandoning several instances of my NSDecinal with a count of 1 and that it seems to be caused by my performOperation method (which calls performQueuedOperation). However, I cannot get rid of one more [operand_retain], because if I do the app crashes because it eventually tries to access an instance of queuedOperand_ that has been deallocated. I may have a defect in my whole model-controller design.

Comment: Your problem is not unique, I see it all to often.  Yes, it is a design problem and there is probably no easy solution.  So, do you care about the leak?  Is enough memory leaked over the life of you app to make a difference?  Do consider the entire life including it being in the background.  If your app can live with the leak let it be, pragmatism often wins over perfection.

Comment: The amount of memory eaten up is small. But since I would like this app to be accepted by Apple, I am concerned for that reason.

Comment: Apple will not reject over memory leaks, I doubt if they even care as long at they do not cause crashes.  There are many other ways to leak memory that are worse than leaks such as retain cycles and retained buy unused memory.  There is even a comment in code I have worked on: "Better to leak that crash".

Comment: I have actually improved it slightly and reduced the leak (slightly). I have also calculated that under normal use, even after many thousands of operations, the leak should not pose a significant memory problem. Onward. Thanks for all the input.

Comment: Respect can be as simple as up-voting the answers and comments of those who have helped, not just here but in the other questions you have asked and the many answers you have read and benefited from, it is a simple click.  You get 2 reputation points for each accepted answer and at 15 can start up-voting answer and thus saying "thanks".  I up-vote answers frequently.

Comment: Can't. Don't have enough reputation points right now. I'll check back later when I do.

Comment: Accepting and up-voting are separate, you did accept your first question. I just up-voted one of your questions to get you over the initial reputation hump.